# Translation of "tressure"

Tags: translation

I’m looking for a translation for the "[tressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orle_(heraldry)#Tressure)" in esperanto about heraldry. I found some words in the PIV, but not this one. Does someone has an idea where I can find such information. Otherwise, how can I translate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [orlo](https://vortaro.net/#orlo_k) is the word I'm looking for.